# Word2vec in php

Tags: php, word2vec

I am fairly new to ML and have no idea how things work, i have a webpage with search bar. and i need  to use word2vec to complete user input in search bar.

i am using this code from https://github.com/donlinglok/C-word2vec-php

```
   <?php

$txtfilepath = fopen("options.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($txtfilepath, filesize("options.txt"));
//fclose($txtfilepath);

function train($txtfilepath) {
    $cbow = 1;
    $size = 500;
    $window = 10;
    $negative = 10;
    $hs = 0;
    $sample = "1e-5";
    $threads = 40;
    $binary = 1;
    $iter = 3;
    $min_count = 10;

    exec ( "cd " . dirname ( __FILE__ ) . "/google-word2vec-trunk && ./word2vec " . " -train " . $txtfilepath . " -output " . dirname ( __FILE__ ) . "/vectors.bin " . " -cbow " . $cbow . " -size " . $size . " -window " . $window . " -negative " . $negative . " -hs " . $hs . " -sample " . $sample . " -threads " . $threads . " -binary " . $binary . " -iter " . $iter . " -min-count " . $min_count, $outputArray );
}
function distance($keyword) {
    exec ( "cd " . dirname ( __FILE__ ) . " && ./distancecli " . dirname ( __FILE__ ) . "/vectors.bin " . $keyword, $outputArray );
    if (isset ( $outputArray[0] )) {
        return $outputArray;
    } else {
        return distance ( $keyword );
    }
}

//train ( dirname ( __FILE__ ) . "/google-word2vec-trunk/questions-words.txt" );
echo json_encode ( distance ( "facebook" ), true );
?>
```

what should i do next ? how to run this code and get result in search bar? i ran it from the web folder http://localhost/trainmodel/word2vec.php and recieved this error Fatal error:

Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\trainmodel\word2vec.php on line 23

Comment: anyone please ??

Comment: Y no one has answered this question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this problem by increasing the max_execution_time value in the php settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).